# How can I NewType wrap an Arc<Mutex<..>> and mutate it across scoped threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust, newtype

Ok, so I want to make a NewType for `Arc<Mutex<MyType>>` because I want to encapsulate the locking in a public API.  ie, locking should occur internally and users don't need to `lock().unwrap()` themselves all over the place, and I want to prevent that anyway.

My problem is that I can't seem to share my NewType across threads and mutate it.  Maybe I am missing a trick, eg impl some missing Trait(s), or maybe it is just not possible...?

I discovered this issue when I tried to write a little program to test the locking in my NewType.  The program runs a loop where each iteration reads all entries and also writes to all entries.  The idea is to ensure that reads see a consistent (snapshot) view of the data.  Here's a simplified version of that program, just wrapping a `Vec<usize>`.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9bab40927186118404943a2fa509085b)

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

struct MyVec{ inner: Arc<Mutex<Vec<usize>>>, }

impl MyVec {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self{ inner: Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![])) }
    }
    
    fn replace(&mut self, vals: &[usize]) {
        let mut lock = self.inner.lock().unwrap();
        lock.clear();
        for v in vals.iter() {
            lock.push(*v);
        }
    }
    
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.inner.lock().unwrap().len()
    }
    
    fn push(&self, v: usize) {
        self.inner.lock().unwrap().push(v);
    }
    
    fn set(&self, k: usize, v: usize) {
        self.inner.lock().unwrap()[k] = v;
    }

    fn get_all(&self) -> Vec<usize> {
        self.inner.lock().unwrap().clone()
    }
}


fn main() {

    let mut vec = MyVec::new();
    for i in 0..500 {
        vec.push(i);
    }
    let orig = vec.get_all();    

    thread::scope(|s| {
    
        for _i in 0..100 {
            let gets = s.spawn(|| {
                assert_eq!(orig, vec.get_all());
            });
    
            let sets = s.spawn(|| {
                for j in 0..vec.len() {
                    vec.set(j, 50);
                }
            });
            let _ = gets.join();
            let _ = sets.join();
    
            vec.replace(&orig);
        }
    });   
}
```

This won't compile.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `vec` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

However, if I replace main() with a version that wraps `MyVec` with an outer `Arc<Mutex<..>>`, then it works.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a4dd3c6a8c2b9fa9f74bf781e0508950)

```
fn main() {

    let vec = MyVec::new();
    for i in 0..500 {
        vec.push(i);
    }
    let orig = vec.get_all();
    
    let vec = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec));
    
    thread::scope(|s| {

        for _i in 0..100 {
            let gets = s.spawn(|| {
                assert_eq!(orig, vec.lock().unwrap().get_all());
            });
    
            let sets = s.spawn(|| {
                let lock = vec.lock().unwrap();
                for j in 0..lock.len() {
                    lock.set(j, 50);
                }
            });
            let _ = gets.join();
            let _ = sets.join();
    
            vec.lock().unwrap().replace(&orig);
        }
    });    
}
```

But that defeats the point of the NewType and I'm back where I started from.

So... is there some way to make the first version compile and run cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace()` needs to take `&self`, it will still work since `Mutex` employs interior mutability.

However, note that your `assert!()` will fail, since you're racing the `set()` and the `get_all()`.

Some other notes: instead of the loop in `replace()` you can use [`extend_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend_from_slice), and the `Arc` is redundant - you can use just `Mutex`.

Comment: thx, good stuff.  I will give some more time for other answers, but will probably accept this one.   I changed `replace()` to take `&self` and it works, as you say.   Unfortunately my real situation is a bit more complicated because these types are implementing a public trait with setter fn that take `&mut self`, and there are already downstream users.  So I will need to think about it.     For benefit of others, here's a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=25169a1cfc46e48e46cf037a7f720f21)  with most of the suggestions implemented.

Comment: [improved playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=be4659e74c45221d2880f9e20edba511).   better demonstrates get_many() inconsistent reads.

Comment: btw, the `Arc` is useful for deriving `Clone` on the NewType.   Though I guess `Rc` would be ok as well in this case...